# Logging with ng serve for CLI angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I have a project running on the CLI for Angular2.  During local development, I'd like to see the http requests the come in.  The server is started using `ng serve`  Does anyone know how to turn logging on for this?

Answer (score 1):

I got error logs by using this command:

```
node 2> widgets.container_err.log ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

The output is not that great, but it does output any errors thrown through node

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box logger for angular 2 cli.

However, there is a compatible library you can install: ng2-logger https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-logger

All you need to do is a simple npm install and import it directly into the files you want to use it (no need to register it in the modules).

Comment: It sounds like @AFrieze is asking how to enable server-side logging, rather than a client-side logging framework like `ng2-logger`...